# How do i implement the take function in Haskell using takeWhile?

Tags: list, function, haskell, definition, take

So in my exam i had to implement the `take` function in Haskell using the `takeWhile`.

How can i do this?

What would be the condition in `takeWhile` so that it will only take the required number of elements from the list?

Because to my understanding in `takeWhile` the condition refers to the elements of the list, not the number of those.

Comment: Hint: `takeWhile` doesn't operate on the original list, and you don't simply return whatever `takeWhile` returns.

Comment: Were you allowed to use any other functions? For instance the `indexed` function

Comment: Your definition might look like `take' n xs = foo (takeWhile p (bar xs))`; your job is to figure out what `foo`, `p`, and `bar` are.

Comment: Well they didn't say we can't use any other functions, but we studied haskell on a really basic level so we only used min, max, take, drop, reverse in our problems

Comment: @chepner so you say i have to modify the list in a way that i can make a condition for it, but idk what foo should be

Comment: To add to @chepner's hints, for `bar` you need to find a way of "annotating" each element with its position in the original list. That will give you a predicate for `takeWhile` to work with that matches what `take` does.

Comment: Start by transforming the input list `[x1,x2,x3,...]` into `[(x1, ...), (x2, ...), (x3, ...), ...]` where each element was paired with some useful information, which can be used later on in the predicate passed in `takeWhile`. You can then discard the additional information afterwards.

Comment: Yes, but will `takeWhile` work with a [(a, Int)] input?

Comment: Because i tried doing something now that you said this but when i write something like `takeWhile (<3) [(1,1), (2,3)]` it gives me an error. How can i make a condition for the second information in the pair?

Comment: `takeWhile` has type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. Just let `a` be `[(b, Int)]` for any type `b`

Comment: Do you know about `fst` and `snd`? You can also pattern-match on the tuple: `\(x,y) -> ...`

Comment: I got stuck on making `takeWhile` accept a `(_, (<10))` input as condition

Comment: How do i "let `a` be `[(b, Int)]` for any type `b`"?

Comment: You don't want a tuple of predicates; you want a predicate that *takes* a tuple.

Comment: @chepner You surely mean "Just let `a` be `(b, Int)` for any type `b`". @DragonS Yes, `takeWhile` works on all lists, including lists of pairs! What you need to do, in such case, is to define a predicate working on pairs. Your `(_, (<10))` attempt is on the right track, even if the syntax is wrong. Try writing a predicate with a lambda: `(\ (x,y) -> ... condition on x and y ...)` and pass that to `takeWhile`.

Comment: Oops, yes. Pretend `takeWhile :: ((b, Int) -> Bool) -> [(b,Int)] -> [(b,Int)]`.

Answer (score 3):

> *to my understanding in `takeWhile` the condition refers to the elements of the list, not the number of those*

Yes! Except, maybe, perhaps, we could somehow make each element reflect the number of its preceding elements in the list, i.e. its *index* in the list.

So we would need to transform our argument list

`[ a,          b,         c,          .... ]`

into a new, modified one, containing the extended information in its elements, e.g.

`[(a, what?), (b, goes?), (c, here?), .... ]`

and then craft some kind of predicate on these *pairs* to do what we want; then recover the original elements from the pairs, following the *decorate--transform--undecorate* paradigm.

If you aren't familiar with the built-in higher-order functions that can accomplish these tasks, you can code them up with recursion, yourself. Or use list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

DONE!!!

Thanks a lot for the help everyone!

I know this could work better but for now this solution worked out.

`index` function:

```
index :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
index [] = []
index x = index2 x 1

index2 :: [a] -> Int -> [(Int, a)]
index2 [] _ = []
index2 (x:xs) i = (i, x) : index2 xs (i+1)
```

`deindex` function:

```
deindex :: [(Int, a)] -> [a]
deindex [] = []
deindex ((i,x):xs) = x : deindex xs
```

`myTake` function using `takeWhile`:

```
myTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
myTake k _
    | k <= 0 = []
myTake _ [] = []
myTake n list = deindex (takeWhile (\ (x,y) -> x<=n) (index list))
```

Comment: when starting to learn a language it's good to be working out the definitions yourself, but now that you've done this, FYI `index xs = zip [1..] xs` and `deindex ixs = map snd ixs = [ x | (_,x) <- ixs]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Im just learning the basics so it helps me to see a problem being solved using other functions.

Comment: you're welcome. first you code these things up yourself as much as you can. then, when you're fed up with it, :) and feel like you can code it up in your sleep and it's not interesting to you anymore, you switch to using the built-in functions that do that for you so you can think about other more interesting stuff. that will later become boring too, hopefully, :) as you master more and more stuff.